# Multibyte characters reading problem in IronPdf

Tags: multibyte-characters, ironpdf

I am trying [IronPDF](https://ironpdf.com/t4/). I want to insert PDF metadata to database which I read with IronPDF. However, some "ı" characters in the metadata are not read with IronPDF. Spaces are left in place of these characters. Here is my code sample:

```
var md = PdfDocument.FromFile("___PATH OF PDF FILE___");
var article_title = md.MetaData.Title;
```

When I copy paste string to Notepad++ it gives a result like this:

[image]

And here is the screenshot of application view:

[image]

Is there a way to solve this problem or is this a bug of IronPDF? If everything goes well, of course, I think of buying. But of course, if it fails on the first try, continue to iTextSharp.

**EDIT:** First of all, I apologize for Windows, which made me surprised. I struggled to get a new system up all day and unfortunately it's still visual studio etc. not to be installed. I added one of the files I had problems with in the below and the IronPDF version appears as 2019.7.0.0.

PDF file: https://yadi.sk/d/HwP9JWRWTzMlSA

Comment: If you could provide such a PDF file _(having Turkish characters in the metadata)_, we could try it better. ;)

Comment: Additionally, specifying the exact version of IronPDF that you are using would also help.

Comment: The file you provided does not work with either of my dotnet fiddle samples (IronPDF: `PDF document doesn't contain %PDF header` & iTextSharp: `PDF header signature not found.`). After using an online converter, they work but not able to show Turkish characters correctly. :(

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, this is a forensic medicine article published in 1973. Moreover, the scan was too old. Therefore, I am trying to find a solution as this situation. As I understand it, continue to iTextSharp. Thank you very much for your interest and support.

Comment: This issue has been resolved with IronPdf [2021.9.3678](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPdf/) which introduces the main release of the 2021 Chrome pixel-perfect rendering engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since you haven't provided us with a sample PDF to work with; I've google some Turkish PDF documents having metadata with Turkish characters. This is the file that I came up with: [link](http://www.istanbulsaglik.gov.tr/w/tez/pdf/psikiyatri/dr_isilay_yatkin.pdf)
[image]
As you can see above the *Author* metadata field has `ı` Turkish character.

Then I created a [dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) in order to test this file using IronPDF (with the latest available version - since you haven't specified any):
[sample using IronPDF](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5pdtf5)

The output from this sample is `ElifCakroglu` which is showing the exact same symptom when copied to Notepad++:
[image]

Playing with the encodings did not help resolving this issue. So I created another dotnet fiddle to test your alternative solution which was iTextSharp: [sample using iTextSharp](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7KcQC6)

This time everything was working as it should be: `ElifCakıroglu`

**Note:** I've also tried creating a Word 2016 document and saving it as a PDF then using that file with the above samples and both of them did not work *(not accepting as a valid PDF)* for some reason. After that I tried and online PDF document validator, but the file was fine. Then I used [an online converter](https://docupub.com/pdfconvert/) to change the PDF version with the default settings and used the output PDF with both samples and the surprising thing is that **both of them worked correctly**.

My conclusion is that iTextSharp is working consistently with both documents having metadata with Turkish characters present, while IronPDF works correctly 50% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this issue is resolved and can be tested in the 2020.9 release branch of IronPdf.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPdf/